# Solving an equation applying the IVT

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that the equation $f(x) = f(x+(1/n))$ has solution for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My guess is that defining $g: [0, 1-\frac{1}{n}] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{n}) - f(x)$ and seeing how its sign varies will do the job, hopefully by deriving a contradiction from the assumption that $f(0) = f(1)$, but I don´t know if there is some trick that I´m missing. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** :
$$g(0) + g\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)+...++ g\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right) = f(1)- f(0)=0$$
And the $n$ values cannot be *all strictly* negative or *strictly* positive.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see how to argue. There has to some points where $g$ takes positive an negative values, and from there is an straight application of the IVT

Comment: @MrGran Exactly. You can also argue that: suppose $g(p/n) = \max_{i=0,...,n-1} g(i/n)$ and $g(q/n) = \min_{i=0,...,n-1} g(i/n)$ then $g(p/n) \ge 0$ and $g(q/n) \le 0$. It suffices to apply the IVT on the 2 points $p/n$ and $q/n$.

Comment: Oh I can see that argument too, because g is continuos and defined on a compact set the range is also compact and so g attains it’s maximum and minimum value at some point in that set.